# Test methods fail using Storage. Illuminate\Http\Testing\imagepng() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, tdd

Hello, I'm doing TDD to test my development, my tests were passing until I decided to reinstall php to repair the `sqlite` driver for testing (the main driver is `mysql`). So when I run my hole suite of tests this error shows in every method that uses the `storage`:

> Error : Call to undefined function Illuminate\Http\Testing\imagepng() 
>   {laravel}/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Testing/FileFactory.php:46 
>   {laravel}/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:1038 
>   {laravel}/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Testing/FileFactory.php:49 
>   {laravel}/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Testing/FileFactory.php:31 
>   {laravel}/tests/Feature/FacilityTest.php:38

This one is a method that throws the above error (the line `38` is signaled):

```php
/**
 * @test
 * Test for: a Facility can be registered by an admin.
 */
public function a_facility_can_be_registered_by_an_admin()
{
    /** Given a correct information for a facility */
    \Storage::fake('public');

   // Next line is line 38, the problematic one:
    $data = ["name" => "AAA", 'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('aaa.jpg')];

    /** When the request is made by an admin */
    $admin = $this->createUser([], 'admin');
    $response = $this->apiAs($admin, 'POST', '/api/v1/manage/facilities', $data);

    /** Then the facility should be registered */
    $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

I really don't know why.

---

If this helps, this is my phpunit file:

**phpunit.xml**

```php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

---

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Whatever is executing your tests needs to have the PHP GD extension

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem and installed PHP GD Extension

Here's the code I placed in my `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

`Note: Installing gd requires that you have libzip, libpng e.t.c`